# What's wrong with the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table called `Std_Components` which acts like an index for list of components with associated tables. The column `AssociatedTable` holds the name of table that actually contains the component data.

Please check images below -

[image]

Here is table data for `Std_SteeringPumps`

[image]

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will copy `Std_Components` table as well as all associated tables with new name. For ex. Lets say if i provided 001 as a parameter to this stored procedure i should be able create new tables like `C001_Components`, `C001_SteeringPumps` and so on.

This is what I have done so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sgi_sp_CreateTablesForNewCompany]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @CompanyId varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   -- declare variables
    declare @qry as varchar(2000)
    declare @compTblName as varchar(100)
    set @compTblName = 'C'+@companyId +'_Components'

    -- Check if table already exists
    IF object_id(@compTblName) is not null
        return

     -- Create main component index table by copying standard component table --
    set @qry = 'Select * into '+@compTblName+' From Std_Components;';
    --print @qry
    --execute (@qry)

    set @qry =@qry + 'Update C'+@companyId +'_Components Set AssociatedTable=''C'+@companyId +'''+substring(AssociatedTable,4,200);';
    --print @qry
    --exec @qry

    -- Create all child tables --
    Select * Into #TempTbl From dbo.Std_Components

    Declare @Id int

    While (Select Count(*) From #TempTbl) > 0
    Begin

        declare @rowTableName as varchar(50)
        declare @compNewTbl as varchar(50)

        Select Top 1 @rowTableName=AssociatedTable, @Id = Id From #TempTbl
        set @compNewTbl = 'C'+@companyId + substring(@rowTableName,4,200);

        set @qry = @qry + 'Select * into '+@compNewTbl+' From ' + @rowTableName + ';'
        --print @qry
        --exec @qry

        Delete #TempTbl Where Id = @Id

    End

    print @qry
    exec @qry
END
```

Here is the output of the print statement for the query it generates -

```
Select * into C001_Components From Std_Components;
Update C001_Components Set AssociatedTable='C001'+substring(AssociatedTable,4,200);
Select * into C001_SteeringPumps From Std_SteeringPumps;
```

But when the stored procedure is executed, I get the following error -

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sgi_sp_CreateTablesForNewCompany, Line 56
>   The name 'Select * into C001_Components From Std_Components;Update C001_Components Set AssociatedTable='C001'+substring(AssociatedTable,4,200);Select * into C001_SteeringPumps From Std_SteeringPumps;' is not a valid identifier.

Can anybody help me out resolve this issue.

Thanks for sharing your time and wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is because the EXEC statement (the last line of the stored procedure) needs to have brackets around the @qry variable so that it becomes

> exec(@qry)

Without the brackets it's treating the entire SQL string as stored procedure name.

Answer (score 1):

The non valid indentifier is around the AssociatedTable part

`Set AssociatedTable='C001'+substring(AssociatedTable,4,200);` will not run as there is no scope for AssociatedTable to substring - the string needs to contain the name of the table completely to be able to be executed

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
exec @qry;
```

You need

```
exec sp_executesql @qry;
```

You'll also need to change the type of @qry to `NVARCHAR`. Note that because of the dynamic sql, the proc is prone to SQL Injection and other escaping issues (i.e. ensure that `@CompanyId` is validated)